# GWT: JavaScript error with opera

Tags: javascript, gwt, opera

We have a large GWT app. Since some days we've got a strange error in opera, all other browser are fine:

```
Syntax error at line 3739 while loading:
f+Gcd(ead)+LIf+A9c.b.b+RIf+Icd(ead)+LIf+
--------------------^
input too deeply nested
```

I've google for "input too deeply nested" but can't find anything related to our problem. Its hard to debug cause there you cant run the app in development mode, but only with compiled JavaScript.

Comment: In the worse case, try to rollback until the error disappears. At least you will know what change in your code created the error.

Comment: `LIf+A9c.b.b` what is last `b` ? because marker clearly point there. And what version of Opera are you using ( old / 11.51 / alpha 12) ?

Comment: @c69: didn't know what b is cause its compiled code

Comment: hmm.. try most fresh alpha build of Opera, if problem persists - just start old-school debug .. by rolling back / commenting out chunks of code, until you find the offender. Because i can't event find this error on google, so you might be first person to actually mention triggering it in the Internet.

Comment: You might  want to check out [PATCH-538](http://my.opera.com/sitepatching/blog/2011/11/14/required-or-not-required) or Opera's Browser.js file. _Pre-process script to avoid "too deeply nested input" error, internal limits in Opera's ES engine too low on qq.com_. (this patch seems to replace calls to underscore.js with their results, because it searches for  patterns like `+_("anychar")+` in page scripts, and replaces them with result of `_("anychar")` operation.

Answer (score 2):

Carakan's parser is a fairly simple recursive-decent one. As such, to avoid blowing the stack, there's a depth limit on input tokens. Nested "+" expressions can cause it, though there is some protection against that (though I forget exactly what, will check and edit this later).

Answer (score 0):

Very late response, but possibly helpful for other users?

Opera (or Opera Mini in our case) can still choke on deeply nested expressions.  Minification tools such as Google's Closure Compiler or UglifyJS will recompile Javascript source code and can introduce much more complex (and deeper) expressions than the original source would suggest.

For [Uglifier](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier) in Ruby on Rails 4, turning off compress.sequences is usually enough to fix the problem.  In **config/environments/production.rb**:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(:compress => {:sequences => false})
```